# Cannot create more than a method in Endpoint class in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been trying to create some new method in my generated Endpoint class and I found this strange behavior: I can add a method to the generated class, but I cannot add two of them, no matter which of the two I add. 
This is the code of my generated class, where I added a code for the two added methods:

```
  package it.raffaele.bills;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor;
import com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JDOCursorHelper;

@Api(name = "utenteendpoint")
public class UtenteEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
     * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
     *
     * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
     * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    public CollectionResponse<Utente> listUtente(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        PersistenceManager mgr = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        List<Utente> execute = null;

        try {
            mgr = getPersistenceManager();
            Query query = mgr.newQuery(Utente.class);
            if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
                cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
                HashMap<String, Object> extensionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursor);
                query.setExtensions(extensionMap);
            }

            if (limit != null) {
                query.setRange(0, limit);
            }

            execute = (List<Utente>) query.execute();
            cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

            // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
            // for lazy fetch.
            for (Utente obj : execute)
                ;
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }

        return CollectionResponse.<Utente> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }

    /**
     * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
     * @return The entity with primary key id.
     */
    public Utente getUtente(@Named("id") Long id) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        Utente utente = null;
        try {
            utente = mgr.getObjectById(Utente.class, id);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return utente;
    }

    /**
     * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
     * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP POST method.
     *
     * @param utente the entity to be inserted.
     * @return The inserted entity.
     */
    public Utente insertUtente(Utente utente) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            if (containsUtente(utente)) {
                throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
            }
            mgr.makePersistent(utente);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return utente;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for updating an existing entity. If the entity does not
     * exist in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
     * It uses HTTP PUT method.
     *
     * @param utente the entity to be updated.
     * @return The updated entity.
     */
    public Utente updateUtente(Utente utente) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            if (!containsUtente(utente)) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
            }
            mgr.makePersistent(utente);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return utente;
    }

    /**
     * This method removes the entity with primary key id.
     * It uses HTTP DELETE method.
     *
     * @param id the primary key of the entity to be deleted.
     * @return The deleted entity.
     */
    public Utente removeUtente(@Named("id") Long id) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        Utente utente = null;
        try {
            utente = mgr.getObjectById(Utente.class, id);
            mgr.deletePersistent(utente);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return utente;
    }


/********************************ADDED CODE*********************************************/

     @SuppressWarnings({"cast", "unchecked"})
        public List<Bill> getUserBillsByTag(@Named("tag") String tag){
         PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
            Utente utente = null;
            List<Bill> list = new LinkedList<Bill>();
            try {
                Query q = mgr.newQuery(Utente.class);
                q.setFilter("nfcID == '" + tag +"'");
                List<Utente> utenti = (List<Utente>) q.execute();
                if (!utenti.isEmpty()){
                    for (Utente u : utenti){
                        list.addAll(u.getBollettini());
                        break;  //fake loop.
                    }

                }else{
                    //handle error

                }


            } finally {
                mgr.close();
            }
            return list;


        }


     @SuppressWarnings({"cast", "unchecked"})
    public List<Bill> getUserBills(@Named("id") Long id){
         Utente utente = getUtente(id);
         System.out.println(utente);
        List<Bill> list = utente.getBollettini();
        return list;
    }


/*******************************************************************************/       


    private boolean containsUtente(Utente utente) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        boolean contains = true;
        try {
            mgr.getObjectById(Utente.class, utente.getId());
        } catch (javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException ex) {
            contains = false;
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return contains;
    }

    private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
        return PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    }

}
```

Do you know how to help me? Am I missing something?

Comment: You said 'cannot add', but can you tell me what actually happened?

Comment: Yes sure: if I add another custom method the generation of the endpoint client library fails. Given that the current version of the APIs returns no detailed errors, it is almost impossible to understand why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your methodes have the same api description (`path="utenteendpoint/{param}"`). 
Give one of them a different path:

```
@ApiMethod(path="utenteendpoint/tag/{tag}/")
public List<Bill> getUserBillsByTag(@Named("tag") String tag) { ... }

@ApiMethod(path="utenteendpoint/user/{id}/")
public List<Bill> getUserBills(@Named("id") Long id) { ... }
```

Comment: The method you quoted is private and it does not affect the code above. First of all, it is generated by the Google toolkit itself and, as described in my question, inside the code section I marked there are the two methods I'm talking about. Adding only one of the two is OK for the compilation process to succeed. Adding both the two is not.

Comment: sorry, I changed my answer.